# Website is not visible in browser, but code is loaded

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

This is a weird thing. I copied my website to a subdomain. On the main domain working fine, but on subdomain just code loading (I can it check with `View Source`), but the page is not showing.

No error messages in Chrome or in Firefox...

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)tiny_mce_popup\.js$ /d_text.cgi?act=tiny_mce_popup.js [L]
RewriteRule (.*)sitemap\.xml$ /d_text.cgi?act=sitemap.xml [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.cgi?act=select&htmlfile=$1 [QSA]
```

Anybody meet with this problem?

Comment: Are you using htaccess for your main domain?

Comment: yes, and it's copied too... the code is loadin, only the page is not rendering in browsers...

Comment: check the htaccess file for any mention of your main domain, and replace with your subdomain.

Comment: Have you modified your base path when you copied the root htaccess file?

Comment: CSS was not modified. Everything is just the same on the main domain.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not about the htaccess, because I can visit every CSS, JS files and the HTML code.

Comment: please post a copy of your htaccess file, and also if possible check your web server error logs. Depending on the OS you should find them under /var/log if using linux. a look at what HTML is being served (or even a link) may help too.

Comment: I was updated the post with .htaccess file's content. Checked the webservers error.log, nothing relevant information.

Comment: A link to the website would be nice for css / html reasons?

Comment: Which `content-type` does your server send along the html content?

Comment: Everything is fine. I was removed the Google Analytics tracking code, and now working fine on subdomains too. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Need to remove the Google Analytics tracking code.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the code
from

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase /SUB-DOMAIN-FOLDER-NAME/
```